# Horizontal scrolling bar on Users page

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

I noticed a horizontal scrolling bar above the footer on the Users page. This happens in any browser on Mac OS 10.6.8.

[image]

**Update 11/10/2012:** I’ve just seen this bug again. I’ll nominate the question for reopening.

[image]

**Update 24/12/2012:** This one is still here. And it even shifts the avatar hats.

[image]

Comment: What's your screen resolution? Does this horizontal scroll bar show up only at smaller sizes?

Comment: @JW01 1440 x 900. I don't know, but now it doesn't happen anymore, so it was either solved or it was a glitch.